# Latex Reference Issue

Tags: bibtex, overleaf

I have the following two references:

```
@techreport{NBERw25194,
 title = {Financing the Response to Climate Change: The Pricing and Ownership of U.S. Green Bonds},
 author = {Baker, Malcolm and Bergstresser, Daniel and Serafeim, George and Wurgler, Jeffrey},
 institution = {National Bureau of Economic Research},
 type = {Working Paper},
 series = {Working Paper Series},
 number = {25194},
 year = {2018}
}

@article{baker2020asset,
  title={Asset prices and portfolios with externalities},
  author={Steven Baker and Burton Hollifield and Emilio Osambela},
  year={2020},
  journal={Available at SSRN: https://ssrn.com/abstract=3344940}
}
```

On its own, `NBERw25194` works fine and appears as "Baker et al. (2018)" in the text. When I include both `NBERw25194` and `baker2020asset`, both these references appear as "M. Baker et al. (2018)" and "S. D. Baker et al. (2020)", respectively. I am using `\cite{}` and tried a few things but so far nothing worked.

Anyone has any suggestions on how to rectify this issue.

Comment: The question is tagged with both "BibTeX" and "`biblatex`". While `biblatex` can be used together with BibTeX it generally is not (it is used with Biber) and what's more it is incompatible with normal BibTeX styles. For a solution it is crucial we know which system you use: Do you load the `biblatex` package or do you have a `\bibliographystyle` instruction in your document?

Comment: The "BibTeX"-`biblatex` distinction is not everything, though, the bibliography (and if applicable citation style) you are using also plays a role in the output. Some styles automatically disambiguate different authors with the same family name by adding given name initials to make the citation labels unique. This feature may or may not be configurable depending on the style you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I use \bibliographystyle only. But the years are different.

Comment: The best way to address the two comments above in the most efficient way with the least chance for confusion is to show us a compilable example document that reproduces the output you are describing with as little code as possible. (This is often called an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. The document should start with `\documentclass` have a short preamble and a little dummy content between `\begin{document}...\end{document}`, but generally as little code as possible,)

Comment: I think you're right. As it turned out, having multiple papers with different authors with same last name, regardless of year, is not compatible with \bibliographystyle{apacite}.

Comment: Well, it is not that it is incompatible with `apacite`, APA style just wants the given name initials in that case to avoid confusion as to which Baker is which: https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2014/01/when-to-use-author-initials-for-text-citations.html (note that the year can indeed be different: this is not primarily about the citation labels being unique, it is about the specific first author names being unique)